# Created OutLook VSTO Add-In Project in VisualStudio 2019 , how to show a image in place of default ribbon text?

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, visual-studio-2019, outlook-addin

I am trying to implement - Read email panel using a button with custom image using "outlook VSTO Add-In".

With below code, I am able to add a "Read a Loud Button" to home toolbar but my requirement is to add a button with custom image to Read email window, Could you please suggest how to achieve this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

```
    private Office.CommandBar newToolBar;
    private Office.CommandBarButton newToolBarButton;
    private System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer syn = new System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Add new Toolbar, if not exist
        if (newToolBar == null)
        {
            newToolBar = Application.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars.Add("MyToolBar", Office.MsoBarPosition.msoBarTop, false, true);
            // Add Button to Toolbar
            newToolBarButton = (Office.CommandBarButton)newToolBar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, missing, true);
            newToolBarButton.Caption = "Stop Voice";
            newToolBarButton.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Core._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(newToolBarButton_Click);
            newToolBar.Visible = true;
        }
        Application.NewMailEx += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailExEventHandler(Application_NewMailEx);
    }

    // New Mail Event Handler
    void Application_NewMailEx(string EntryIDCollection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (((Outlook.MailItem)this.Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection, missing)).UnRead)
            {
                var body = ((Outlook.MailItem)this.Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection, missing)).Body;
                var subject = ((Outlook.MailItem)this.Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection, missing)).Subject;
                var sender = ((Outlook.MailItem)this.Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection, missing)).SenderName;                    
                syn.SpeakAsync("Mail From " + sender + "Subject is " + subject + body);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    void newToolBarButton_Click(Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
    {
        syn.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Command bars were deprecated. Instead, you need to use the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI). The following articles explain how to create a custom UI for the ribbon:

- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019)
- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019)

The Fluent UI is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)